# Gatsby Build stucks on task "Building static HTML for pages"

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I have the problem, that every time I run my "**gastby build**" command (**I ran before "gastby clean"**), that it stucks on the task "**Building static HTML for pages**" with 0 percent and does not finish the build.

My tech stack is:

- "gatsby": "^4.18.0"
- "react": "^18.1.0"
- "react-dom": "^18.1.0"
- "theme-ui": "^0.3.4"
- "@emotion/core": "^10.3.1",
- "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",

I identified that the problem is caused by the following code in my **Header.Menu.jsx**:

```
const NaviList = ({ navKey, wrapperProps, items, items2, ...props }) =>
  items ? (
    <Flex {...wrapperProps}>
      {items.map((menuItem, index) => (
        <>
          <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index}`} {...menuItem} {...props} />
          <Box sx={styles.secondUl}>
            {items2.map((menuItem2, index2) => (
              <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index2}`} {...menuItem2} {...props} />
            ))}
          </Box>
        </>
      ))}
    </Flex>
  ) : null
```

When I uncomment the second JavaScript map `items2.map()` then my gastby build runs without problems and finishes the build compeletly without getting stucked.

```
const NaviList = ({ navKey, wrapperProps, items, items2, ...props }) =>
  items ? (
    <Flex {...wrapperProps}>
      {items.map((menuItem, index) => (
        <>
          <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index}`} {...menuItem} {...props} />
          <Box sx={styles.secondUl}>
            {/*{items2.map((menuItem2, index2) => (*/}
            {/*  <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index2}`} {...menuItem2} {...props} />*/}
            {/*))}*/}
          </Box>
        </>
      ))}
    </Flex>
  ) : null
```

But how can I achive that my JSX component can use these nested JavaScript Maps `items.map()` and `items2.map()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that items2 may arrive `null` or `undefined` when compiling at that point of the code. Try adding an optional chaining or a condition like:

```
{items2 && items2.map((menuItem2, index2) => (
  <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index2}`} {...menuItem2} {...props} />
))}
```

You can also avoid this condition by specifying default values in your component in case they arrive with a falsy value:

```
const NaviList = ({ navKey, wrapperProps, items=[], items2=[], ...props }) =>
  items ? (
    <Flex {...wrapperProps}>
      {items.map((menuItem, index) => (
        <>
          <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index}`} {...menuItem} {...props} />
          <Box sx={styles.secondUl}>
            {items2 && items2.map((menuItem2, index2) => (
              <NaviItem key={`${navKey}-${index2}`} {...menuItem2} {...props} />
            ))}
          </Box>
        </>
      ))}
    </Flex>
  ) : null
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me and now my "gastby build" command completes the build successfully.